# Convert statement from English to logic: "to pass philosophy it is not necessary to make notes every week"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I saw this on a previous thread,

> To pass philosophy it is not necessary to make notes every week.

Let $p = \text{Pass phil}$ and $m = \text{make notes}$,

Then basically what the sentence is is,

**if** you take notes **or** you don't take notes, **then** you will pass philosophy.

So is it

> $m \lor \neg m \implies p$

?

Comment: So ... you are saying it is impossible to fail philosophy?

Comment: It is not nescessary to take notes to pass = not true (not taking notes => failing philosophy = $\lnot (\lnot m \implies \lnot p)$

Comment: @fleablood Which is logically equivalent to just $\lnot m \land p$ "you won't take notes and you'll pass"... :P

Comment: ooh.... good point.  The statement is $\lnot m \land p$ is possible.  We need instance and quantifiers $\lnot (\forall x| \lnot M(x) \implies \lnot P(x))$.

Comment: @fleablood indeed, a form of quantifiers cannot be avoided here :)

Comment: I'm a little weak on my nescessitate quantifiers.  I seem to remember studying that they were impossible but that does not make sense.  The forall and there exist aren't nescessarily correct in the universe of instances that *are* but I don't see why we can have a universe of things that may or may not be.  I'm just not sure what these are if they are not "for all" and "there exist".

Comment: "Necessary" means that if the consequent is true then the antecedent could be true. Or if consequent is false then antecedent is false. But "not necessary" says there's no relation between the consequent's truth value and the antecedent's. Out of the 16 possible two operand logical connectives of $p$ and $q$, this connective, (call it $\bullet$ for sake of discussion) is $p \bullet q = p$.

Answer (score 1):

If this was given as part of a logic assignment, it was a poor example.
Many statements in English cannot be converted into logical form using the standard propositional logic ($p$, $q$, $\land$, $\lor$, $\lnot$, $\to$, etc.). This is true in your case, and the reason is the use of the term *necessary*. Usually, statements about necessity can only be correctly expressed with [Modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) (or some other form of [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic))). We use $\Box$ to mean "it is necessary that". In this case, we could write the statement:
$$
\lnot \Box (p \to m)
$$
which we read "It is not necessarily true that if you pass, you took notes."

The problem with your suggestion,
$$
(m \lor \lnot m) \to p,
$$
is that it says "whether you take notes or not, you will pass" which the speaker certainly did not intend to imply!
User @fleablood also had a suggestion,
$$
\lnot (\lnot m \to \lnot p).
$$
This one is better; it seems to read as "it is not the case that if you take don't take notes, you won't pass". But taking a closer look, it's logically equivalent to $\lnot m \land p$, so it just says "you won't take notes and you'll pass", which makes no sense.

(The reason @fleablood's translation didn't work has a lot to do with the word "if". "If" in English usually doesn't correspond very well to the logical connective $\to$. There are whole areas of philosophy devoted to translating English statements correctly, but one popular way that seems quite effective is to use the $\Box$ I mentioned earlier.)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence boils down to "It is not that case that if you never take note you fail" or it is not the case that for all cases, if you don't take notes you will fail.

So $x$ = a potential student.  $M(x)$= x takes notes.  $P(x)$ = x passes.

$\lnot (\forall x|(\lnot M(x)) \implies (\lnot P(x)))$.

Although it is important to realize that $\forall$ does not mean all students that actually take the class but all hypothetical students that could take the class.  There might not actually be a student who didn't take notes and passed but there *could* be.

Maybe... There may be more to this.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence "to pass Philosophy it's not necessary to take notes every week," is followed by, "indeed Alice did it last semester," then we may be tempted to translate it with

$$ \neg\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow T(x)) \enspace. $$

We would interpret "it's possible" as an understatement for "it's been done."  It's not clear that this strengthening is justified.  If, on the other hand, the sentence is followed by, "suppose a student had superhuman memory," then we are better off translating into modal logic:

$$\neg\Box\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow T(x)) \enspace.$$

With or without alethic modalities, I'd go with a first-order logic.  "Alice passed philosophy" and "it's raining" are sentences; "to pass philosophy" and "to take notes" are not.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is that taking notes and passing philosophy are not correlated.  There is no implication in either direction between $P$ and $M$.  All four assignments of truth values to $P$ and $M$ are allowed.

Also, your proposed answer isn't correct as it's a tautology.

Comment: So what is the correct statement>

Comment: @gar It would be that taking notes does not imply passing philosophy.  So $\neg (M\rightarrow P)$

Comment: Actually I disagree with the first paragraph. It's not saying anything about correlation, but rather what is necessary. Notes will probably help you pass, they just aren't necessary.

Comment: You made the mistake I made.  -> is not causality so the only way for M ->P to be false is if you take notes and you fail.  So not(M -> P) means "you do take notes and do fail".

Comment: @fleablood Right, you are.  Then I stand by the statement in my answer.  All four assignments of truth values to $P$ and $M$ are possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might use:  $(m\land p) \lor  (\neg m \land p)$ which is equivalent to $p$.

See truth table at: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+((m%26p)or(~m%26p))